# Google App Engine - Java - Deployment failed for JSP compilation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, exception, deployment

I'm coding a website with Google App Engine, on Slim3 framework, I'm trying to deploy my code but Eclipse report me this exception:

```
    Unable to update:
    com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:628)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:479)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:339)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:407)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Obviously the deployment won't complete. How can I do to know what JSP files actually contains bugs?

Typical code page:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" session="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.slim3.org/functions"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/Italy.ico">
<title>${f:h(titolo)} - Associazione nazionale ricerca e sviluppo energie rinnovabili</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <%@ include file="/Home/header.jsp"%>

    <%@ include file="/Home/menu.jsp"%>

    <div id="content">
    <p id="orientationInfo"><a href="/Home">Home</a> > <a href="/Home/Progetti">Progetti</a> > ${f:h(titolo)}</p>
        <center><H2>${f:h(titolo)}</H2></center>

        <H3>Descrizione</H3>
        <p class="paragrafo">${f:h(descrizione)}</p>

        <H3>Anno di inizio</H3>
        <p class="paragrafo">${f:h(anno)}</p>       

        <c:set var="partnerUrl" value="Progetto/Partners?key=${f:h(key)}&version=${version}"/>
        <H3><a href="${f:url(partnerUrl)}">Partners</a></H3>

        <c:set var="eventiUrl" value="Progetto/Eventi?key=${f:h(key)}&version=${version}"/>
        <H3><a href="${f:url(eventiUrl)}">Eventi Promozionali</a></H3>

        <c:set var="eventiUrl" value="Progetto/Risultati?key=${f:h(key)}&version=${version}"/>
        <H3><a href="${f:url(eventiUrl)}">Risultati</a></H3>


    </div>

    <%@ include file="/Home/footer.jsp"%>

</div>
</body>
</html>


header.jsp
<div id="header">
    <center>
        <h1>Associazione nazionale ricerca e sviluppo energie rinnovabili</h1>
    </center>
</div>

menu.jsp
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/Progetti">PROGETTI</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/Eventi">EVENTI</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/Partners">PARTNERS</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

footer.jsp
<div id="footer">
    <ul id="footer">
            <li>
                <span>
                <a href="/Home/ChiSiamo">CHI SIAMO</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>
                <a href="/Home/ProfiloDiRicerca">PROFILO DI RICERCA</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>
                <a href="/Home/Contatti">CONTATTI</a>
                </span>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: We'll need more info. What's the jsp code? There might be a syntax error in your jsp code.

Comment: I have a lot of jsp page and I don't know what the wrong page.
I added the typical code in the question.